# ASP: Repeater in VB.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I am using Visual studio! (telerik is like gridview, same stuff)
I am like dying slowly trying to create a scheduler with ASP: Repeater!!!
Someone please save me from this never-ending torture! lol

GOAL: This is a page for patients to make appointments! So, the page has a grid that shows the doc's information along with their availability (TimeSlot)!  [PLEASE refer to attached image]

---.ASPX----
Below is the ASPX code (front side)

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_provider_details" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDS_provider_detail"
                        Height="700px" Skin="Metro" Width="100%" PageSize="3" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <GroupingSettings CollapseAllTooltip="Collapse all groups"></GroupingSettings>
                        <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SDS_provider_detail" Font-Size="Large" DataKeyNames="provider_code">
                            <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                There is no result with the selected filter.
                            </NoRecordsTemplate>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="providerFullName" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Height="200px"
                                HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="providerFullName" UniqueName="providerFullName">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="taxonomy_desc" HeaderText="Specialty" ReadOnly="True"
                                SortExpression="taxonomy_desc" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="addr1" HeaderText="Address" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="addr1"
                                HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_appt" runat="server" DataSourceID="SDS_Repeater_appt">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_appt" Text="YEAH"></asp:Label>--%>
                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_haha" Text='<%# Eval("timeslot") %>' Font-Size="Large"
                                                Width="100px" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_more_appt" Text="More" Font-Size="Large" Width="100px" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                        </Columns>
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="item-style" />
                        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="item-style" />
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings>
                        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" ScrollHeight="650px"></Scrolling>
                    </ClientSettings>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDS_Repeater_appt" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDS_provider_detail" runat="server">
                    <SelectParameters>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

---.VB-----

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Partial Class Appointment
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub RadGrid_provider_details_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs) Handles RadGrid_provider_details.ItemDataBound
    'This sub gets activated so I can get the provider-code for the providers...I don't get it too well
    'The provider code is required to get the availability for the doctors, and it is from the datasource of the grid
    'Here is also where I call the BindRepeater_retrieveTimeSlotAvailbility() '

        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
            Dim item As GridDataItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
            Dim provider_code As String = item.GetDataKeyValue("provider_code").ToString()

            Dim item2 As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
            Dim Repeater_appt As Repeater = DirectCast(item2.FindControl("Repeater_appt"), Repeater)

            BindRepeater_retrieveTimeSlotAvailbility(provider_code, Repeater_appt)

        End If

    End Sub


Private Sub BindRepeater_retrieveTimeSlotAvailbility(ByVal provider_code As String, ByRef Repeater_appt As Repeater)
        initializeScheduler()

        Dim SQlstr As String, RtnStr As String
        Dim selected_org_code As String = ""
        selected_org_code = DDL_Clinic.SelectedValue
        HF_OrgCode.Value = selected_org_code
        Dim connectionStr As String = ""
        connectionStr = GetClientConnectionStringByOrgCode(selected_org_code)
        Dim errormsg As String = ""
        SQlstr = "select office_location from locations where facility_name= '" & DDL_Clinic.SelectedItem.Text & "'"
        Dim office_location As String = PubFunc.SelectOneBySQL2(SQlstr, connectionStr, errormsg)
        If errormsg <> "" Then
            MessageDisplayInModal(errormsg, True)
        End If

        If provider_code <> "" Then
            Dim In_String As String = "'0',"
            In_String &= "'" & provider_code & "'," & "'0'"
            '===========================

            Dim dateToSchedule As DateTime
            dateToSchedule = txt_DateToSchedule.Text
            dateToSchedule.ToShortDateString()


            time_slot_SQL2(SQlstr, dateToSchedule.ToShortDateString(), office_location, RtnStr, In_String, day_start, day_end)


            ''Added by HELPER, but I didn't get it.. it gives me a 'Both datasource and datasourceID are defined on 'Repeater_appt' Remove one definition' error
            'Execute SQlstr and get datatable.
            'Datatable dt = Result of SQlstr
            'Repeater_appt.DataSource = SQlstr
            'Repeater_appt.DataBind()

            SDS_Repeater_appt.SelectCommand = SQlstr
            SDS_Repeater_appt.ConnectionString = connectionStr
            SDS_Repeater_appt.DataBind()
        End If

 Protected Sub time_slot_SQL2(ByRef SQLStr As String, ByVal dateToSchedule As String, ByVal office_location As String, ByVal RtnStr As String, ByVal In_String As String, ByVal day_start As String, ByVal day_end As String)
'The original sql is super long, basically, just return the SQLstr (byRef) to where it calls it! (just to make code neater)
        SQLStr = "SELECT TOP 5 timeslot from appt where provider_code = '100'"

End Sub
End Class
```

'RESULT of what's happening when I run the codes:
Test Data: Suppose to have 3 test providers (provider1, provider2, provider3; they all have diff TIMESLOT)

Code run:

1. Calls RadGrid_provider_details_ItemDataBound once; e.item is NOT a
   GridDataItem, so it exit sub
2. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is a GridDataItem, get provider1’s
   providercode it goes through the code, and calls BindRepeater_retrieveTimeSlotAvailbility(provider_code, repeater_appt)
3. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is NOT a GridDataItem, so it exit
   sub
4. Goes to the front (aspx), and EVAL (timeslot) 5 times
5. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is a GridDataItem, provider2’s providercode2, and goes through
6. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is NOT a GridDataItem, so it exit
   sub
7. Goes back to the front (aspx) again, and runs 5 times
8. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is a GridDataItem, provider3’s providercode3, and goes through
9. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is NOT a GridDataItem, so it exit
   sub
10. Calls ItemDataBound again, e.item is NOT a GridDataItem, so it exit
     sub
11. RadGrid_provider_detail.databind()
12. Goes back to the front (aspx) again, and runs 15 times and done…

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: why not use an existing GUI scheduler, there are several on the market (e.g. this one is quite good IMHO, you can interact with it nicely using JSON to/from your server: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/) and save yourself the world of pain and code spaghetti that is the asp.net repeater control (horrible memories for me, glad I don't have to work with it any more, MVC etc is like coming from the darkness into light compared to the Forms debacle, which is fundamentally anti-www in its design concept - a kludge and a sop to VB6 devs who'd never seen a webpage before in 2002). Rant over :-)

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, O_O can you elaborate or send me some link on why it's 'begging to be hacked

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I actually fixed my repeater...but yeah, it was a pain.... but now I got scared cuz the guy who commented above u said its very bad code (T.T)

Comment: No worries, glad you solved it. P.S. I agree it's bad code - this is because you build your SQL queries by naively joining strings together instead of using type-safe parameters to include the variables. A clever user can write certain SQL statements into your textboxes which would cause your intended statement not to run as expected, and instead execute other statements designed to steal, corrupt or even destroy your data. http://bobby-tables.com/ provides a humorous but very clear introduction to the topic, as well as some examples of how to build your query properly, including for .NET

Comment: The basic lesson from this is _never_ to trust any input coming from either a user or another external source e.g. an API or 3rd party database. First validate your data against your business rules (e.g. field size, data type, logic rules) and then if it passes that validation, use anti-injection techniques including (but not  necessarily limited to) database query parameters to mitigate the risk of an attack. If you're outputting data into HTML as well you should look into whether you're also vulnerable to script injection (e.g. injecting malicious javascript into your page)

Comment: @Biuechocoo The word "practically" is important here. You're not begging to be hacked in the same way a women who wears suggestive clothes to a disreputable bar is definitely not begging to be raped... but there's still significant foolish unnecessary risk here. Anyone who knows about these or has a script written by someone who knows about these things can craft an HTTP request for your page that puts malicious data in your `DDL_Clinic` field. Something like `'DROP TABLE Locations;--` would do it, but more subtle and damaging queries are trivial. Look at parameterized queries to fix the issue

Comment: @ADyson, wow... i just spoke with my friend.... and understood what you meant completely....OMG, i dont know what am i doing anymore, lmao. Had been working this way for like...sometimes. ARGHHH, and my friend was like " I knew that but we don't have time to make the changes yet..." I want to hit my head to a tree...after knowing the truth...

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Thank you for your reply & suggestion... I just started coding like half  a year ago... and no one had ever corrected the way I wrote my SQL.... I just asked one of my friends now, and he was like, yeah I know it's wrong but no one asks us to change it so..... (my reaction: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHSHEETTTTTTT)